# Pandas for Python, grouping

Tags: pandas

I have a data set consisting of multiple tuples per time stamp - each of these has a count. There could be different tuples present at each time stamp. I would like to group these together in 5 minute bins and add the counts for each unique tuple. Is there a nice clean way to do this using Pandas group-by ?

They have the form:
((u'67.163.47.231', u'8.27.82.254', 50186, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 2)

This is currently a list, with a 6-tuple (last entry is time-stamp), and then count.

There will be a collection of 5-tuples for every time stamp:

(5-tuple), t-time-stamp, count, for example (for just one time stamp)

```
[((u'71.57.43.240', u'8.27.82.254', 33108, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'67.163.47.231', u'8.27.82.254', 50186, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 2),
 ((u'8.27.82.254', u'98.206.29.242', 25159, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'71.179.102.253', u'8.27.82.254', 50958, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1)]

In [220]: df = DataFrame ( { 'key1' : [ (u'71.57.43.240', u'8.27.82.254', 33108, 80, 6), (u'67.163.47.231', u'8.27.82.254', 50186, 80, 6) ], 'data1' : np.array((1,2)), 'data2': np.array((1377565195000,1377565195000))})

In [226]: df
Out[226]: 
   data1          data2                                        key1
0      1  1377565195000   (71.57.43.240, 8.27.82.254, 33108, 80, 6)
1      2  1377565195000  (67.163.47.231, 8.27.82.254, 50186, 80, 6)
```

or converted:

```
In [231]: df = DataFrame ( { 'key1' : [ (u'71.57.43.240', u'8.27.82.254', 33108, 80, 6), (u'67.163.47.231', u'8.27.82.254', 50186, 80, 6) ], 'data1' : np.array((1,2)), 
   .....: 'data2': np.array(( datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1377565195),datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1377565195) )) })

In [232]: df
Out[232]: 
   data1               data2                                        key1
0      1 2013-08-27 00:59:55   (71.57.43.240, 8.27.82.254, 33108, 80, 6)
1      2 2013-08-27 00:59:55  (67.163.47.231, 8.27.82.254, 50186, 80, 6)


Here's a simpler example:

time         count       city
00:00:00       1         Montreal
00:00:00       2         New York
00:00:00       1         Chicago
00:01:00       2         Montreal
00:01:00       3         New York

after bin-ing

time         count       city
00:05:00       3         Montreal
00:05:00       5         New York
00:05:00       1         Chicago
```

Here's what seems to work well:

```
times = [ parse('00:00:00'), parse('00:00:00'), parse('00:00:00'), parse('00:01:00'), parse('00:01:00'),
parse('00:02:00'), parse('00:02:00'), parse('00:03:00'), parse('00:04:00'), parse('00:05:00'),
parse('00:05:00'), parse('00:06:00'), parse('00:06:00') ]
cities = [ 'Montreal', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Montreal', 'New York', 
'New York', 'Chicago', 'Montreal', 'Montreal', 'New York', 'Chicago', 'Montreal', 'Chicago']
counts = [ 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1]
frame = DataFrame( { 'city': cities, 'time': times, 'count': counts } )

In [150]: frame
Out[150]: 
        city  count                time
0   Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:00:00
1   New York      2 2013-09-07 00:00:00
2    Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:00:00
3   Montreal      2 2013-09-07 00:01:00
4   New York      3 2013-09-07 00:01:00
5   New York      1 2013-09-07 00:02:00
6    Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:02:00
7   Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:03:00
8   Montreal      2 2013-09-07 00:04:00
9   New York      2 2013-09-07 00:05:00
10   Chicago      2 2013-09-07 00:05:00
11  Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:06:00
12   Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:06:00

frame['time_5min'] = frame['time'].map(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([0],index=pd.DatetimeIndex([x])).resample('5min').index[0])

In [152]: frame
Out[152]: 
        city  count                time           time_5min
0   Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:00:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
1   New York      2 2013-09-07 00:00:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
2    Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:00:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
3   Montreal      2 2013-09-07 00:01:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
4   New York      3 2013-09-07 00:01:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
5   New York      1 2013-09-07 00:02:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
6    Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:02:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
7   Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:03:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
8   Montreal      2 2013-09-07 00:04:00 2013-09-07 00:00:00
9   New York      2 2013-09-07 00:05:00 2013-09-07 00:05:00
10   Chicago      2 2013-09-07 00:05:00 2013-09-07 00:05:00
11  Montreal      1 2013-09-07 00:06:00 2013-09-07 00:05:00
12   Chicago      1 2013-09-07 00:06:00 2013-09-07 00:05:00

In [153]: df = frame.groupby(['time_5min', 'city']).aggregate('sum')

In [154]: df
Out[154]: 
                              count
time_5min           city           
2013-09-07 00:00:00 Chicago       2
                    Montreal      6
                    New York      6
2013-09-07 00:05:00 Chicago       3
                    Montreal      1
                    New York      2

In [155]: df.reset_index(1)
Out[155]: 
                         city  count
time_5min                           
2013-09-07 00:00:00   Chicago      2
2013-09-07 00:00:00  Montreal      6
2013-09-07 00:00:00  New York      6
2013-09-07 00:05:00   Chicago      3
2013-09-07 00:05:00  Montreal      1
2013-09-07 00:05:00  New York      2
```

Comment: Can you give a short example data of the whole dataframe?

Comment: [((u'71.57.43.240', u'8.27.82.254', 33108, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'67.163.47.231', u'8.27.82.254', 50186, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 2),
 ((u'8.27.82.254', u'98.206.29.242', 25159, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'69.66.156.250', u'8.27.82.254', 59274, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 3),
 ((u'76.16.235.239', u'8.27.84.126', 48104, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'8.27.84.254', u'98.226.117.227', 63795, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 2),
 ((u'24.1.153.243', u'8.27.82.126', 18970, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),
 ((u'76.16.101.243', u'8.27.82.126', 41329, 80, 6, 1377565195000), 1),

Comment: You can edit you question to include it instead of as a comment. Where is the timestamp in this example?

Comment: last entry in the 6-tuple

Comment: Do you already put it in a pandas DataFrame? How does that look like (is the tuple one column)?

Comment: I've not put these into a DataFrame yet. Given this is a list (or a dictionary if I don't sort on the time stamp). But the intent would be to have the tuple as a column. But then use the time-stamp as a time-series - to really the first 5-tuple is the unique key, then the time-stamp, and the count.

Comment: How is the timestamp defined? How can it be converted to a datetime?

Comment: The timestamp is time since the UNIX epoch - can be converted to datetime

Comment: In [226]: df
Out[226]: 
   data1          data2                                        key1
0      1  1377565195000   (71.57.43.240, 8.27.82.254, 33108, 80, 6)
1      2  1377565195000  (67.163.47.231, 8.27.82.254, 50186, 80, 6)

Comment: Do you only have timestamps every 5 mins? Or do you have to combine several minutes in one 5 min bins?

Comment: The data needs to be grouped (binned) into 5min bins. There can be multiple (100's of 5-tuples or keys) per time step - and these can change from time step to time step - for each unique key or tuple, want to add together the counts (data1)

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example dataset, and also give an example of the desired output

Comment: Here is a simpler example that illustrates the idea:

Comment: time         count       city
00:00:00       1         Montreal
00:00:00       2         New York
00:00:00       1         Chicago
00:01:00       2         Montreal
00:01:00       3         New York

after bin-ing into 5min bins

time         count       city
00:05:00       3         Montreal
00:05:00       5         New York
00:05:00       1         Chicago

Comment: time         count       city
00:00:00       1         Montreal
00:00:00       2         New York
00:00:00       1         Chicago
00:01:00       2         Montreal
00:01:00       3         New York

after bin-ing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the date as the index you can use TimeGrouper (which allows you to group by, for example, 5 minute intervals):

```
In [11]: from pandas.tseries.resample import TimeGrouper

In [12]: df.set_index('data2', inplace=True)

In [13]: g = df.groupby(TimeGrouper('5Min'))
```

You can then count the number of unique items in each 5 minute interval using nunique:

```
In [14]: g['key1'].nunique()
Out[14]: 
2013-08-27 00:55:00    2
dtype: int64
```

If you're looking for a count of each tuple, you could use value_counts:

```
In [15]: g['key1'].apply(pd.value_counts)
Out[15]: 
2013-08-27 00:55:00  (71.57.43.240, 8.27.82.254, 33108, 80, 6)     1
                     (67.163.47.231, 8.27.82.254, 50186, 80, 6)    1
dtype: int64
```

Note: this is a Series with a MultiIndex (use reset_index to make it a DataFrame).

```
In [16]: g['key1'].apply(pd.value_counts).reset_index(1)
Out[16]: 
                                                        level_1  0
2013-08-27 00:55:00   (71.57.43.240, 8.27.82.254, 33108, 80, 6)  1
2013-08-27 00:55:00  (67.163.47.231, 8.27.82.254, 50186, 80, 6)  1
```

You'll probably want to give these more informative column names :).

*Update: previously I hacked get [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.core.reshape.get_dummies.html), see edit history.*

Comment: I ♥ get_dummies, but there is probably a short-cut for `get_dummies(x).sum()` lol it's value_counts

Comment: Nice trick with the TimeGrouper! But I think he wants to 'add the counts' (which is an existing column), and not to 'count the unique keys'

Comment: Yeah, it should be in the docs! (Also seems a shame you can't do it to a column...)

Comment: But for sure, the counts need to be added

Comment: @StephenThomas I don't understand what you mean, this does count the number of occurrences. If this isn't what you want could you include the desired outcome in your question?

Comment: Sorry - I want to add the counts (data1 column) for unique keys - when binning into 5 min bins -

Comment: in this example there was just one time stamp - but there will be 1000's of time stamps across several minutes up to an hour say.

Comment: this groups these timestamps into 5 minute bins

Comment: ah you want to groupby data1 too (i.e. my solution but also separated by data1)

Comment: essentially add (aggregate) the data1 (counts) for each unique key, into 5 min bins.

Comment: so when there are enough time stamps (data2) spanning more than 5 minutes (e.g an hour), add together the counts(data1) for each of the unique keys appearing (in a given 5min bin or interval). The difficulty is that not all keys will appear or be present for any given time stamp

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add together the counts for each unique tuple, just groupby `key1`:

```
df.groupby('key1').aggregate('sum')
```

If you want to do this for each time step and each unique tuple, you can give multiple column to group by:

```
df.groupby(['data2', 'key1']).aggregate('sum')
```

If different timesteps have to be combined in one 5min bin, a possible approach is to round your timestamp to 5 min, and then group by on that:

```
df['data2_5min'] = (np.ceil(df['data2'].values.astype('int64')/(5.0*60*1000000000))*(5.0*60*1000000000)).astype('int64').astype('M8[ns]')
df.groupby(['data2_5min', 'key1']).aggregate('sum')
```

If you want to preserve some of the original timestamps (but you have to choose which if you are binning them), you can specify a function to apply on the individual columns. For example take the first:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['data2_5min', 'key1']).aggregate({'data1':'sum', 'data2':'first'})
df2.reset_index(0, drop=True).set_index('data2', append=True)
```

If you just want to resample on 5 mins and add the counts regardless of the keys, you can simply do:

```
df.set_index('data2', inplace=True)
df.resample('5min', 'sum')
```

Comment: The keys are unique (but may not appear every time step). I would like to add the data1 (counts) together for each unique key - and then bin these into 5min bins - so the second approach

Comment: So the second approach is what you want? Or not yet?

Comment: This looks way nicer than mine, but it doesn't bin into 5 minute intervals (I guess you could make a column with rounded times?)

Comment: @Andy Yeah, that's what I was trying (rounded times), but it is not clear to me if it is needed (maybe all the times are already 5-mins, and then it is just a simple groupby)

Comment: @Andy Oops, mislooking at the seconds/minutes, so it is certainly not yet in 5-min times ..

Comment: Yeah, as usual here example not the best... Not sure how you do the rounded times (will upvote when you get it :p ).

Comment: I would want the second approach - but it groups together the keys ?

Comment: ideally would want to keep the time-stamp intact, for each unique key - then I understood that the time stamp resample() could handle mutiple keys when resampling ?

Comment: Yes, it groups together the *unique* keys (the tuples). Isn't that what you want?

Comment: How can you keep the time-stamp intact if you want to bin your data every 5 min?

Comment: OK, if you want to keep the time stamp intact, you should not group by it and take the first approach.

Comment: I've read that the time series resample can work with repeated time stamps - I'd really just like to aggregate so that the counts (data1) are added when creating a 5 min time bin. In this example there were just 2 time stamps (same value). A larger data set would have 1000's or more time stamps for keys, and a cound for each. Would like to sum the counts for unique keys when binned

Comment: OK, I get that, but the last approach does this? What do you mean with keep the timestamp intact? If you have two rows with a unique key but different timestamps in the same 5min bin, which of the two timestamps you want to preserve?

Comment: by time-stamp intact, just meant that it is included in the time series or dataframe, even after aggregation

Comment: If you "aggregate" for different timestamps, you cannot just include it (because for each aggregated count, you have multiple and different timestamps). How do you want it included?

Comment: Can you give a more elaborate example dataset (with different timestamps), and also give an example of the desired output.

Comment: would resample() be able to create the 5min bins ? even when there are repeated time stamps

Comment: @Andy, indeed ... That's certainly something that can be improved with a handy function :-)

Comment: I want add the counts (data1) associated with a unique key - so if a (count,key) appears for a time stamp in any 5 min interval, the counts are added. Do not want to add counts for all keys in the 5 min bin.

Comment: OK, but in that case, I think my answer is working (with the rounding)?

Comment: @Andy Lol, another hack to round :-) `df['data2'].map(lambda x: pd.DataFrame([0],index=pd.DatetimeIndex([x])).resample('5min').index[0])`

Comment: in the case of df.set_index('data2', inplace=True)
df.resample('5min', 'sum'), it is adding toegther counts for all the keys - want to keep the counts for the unique keys separated

Comment: In that case all counts are added, also for non-unique within a 5 min bin. So that is not what you want. But my third code block is doing what you want I think?

Comment: That block adds together the counts (data1) for all keys - need to keep the unique keys separate - need the counts added for each unique key when binned - so in this case would not change - need to have more time stamps that span several minutes

Comment: This ``df.groupby(['data2_5min', 'key1']).aggregate('sum')`` keeps the keys seperate, and adds the counts within each 5 min bin together for the unique keys

Comment: Would it be possible let resample() create the 5min bins - afterwards and preserve the unique keys (along with their counts).

Comment: This would allow for example, to create 2 min, 10 min bins using resample - and look at the data over different bin sizes (time scales)

Comment: I've posted a much simpler example (based on cities as keys) above